# Solving date range for continuity (GAPS AND ISLANDS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below where the column `X` are the prices of an item between the given start and end period.

```
X    START_DATE     END_DATE
------------------------------    
1    01-01-2014     01-01-2016
2    01-04-2014     01-05-2014
3    01-07-2014     01-08-2014
```

However  the first entry is defined for a bigger range of time period which should be considered only when the item price is not defined for monthly periods, similar to second and third record or when certain range is missing. Now the desired out put is

```
X    START_DATE      END_DATE
------------------------------    
1    01-01-2014     01-04-2014
2    01-04-2014     01-05-2014
1    01-05-2014     01-07-2014
3    01-07-2014     01-08-2014
1    01-08-2014     01-01-2016
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you please post the query what you have tried so far ??

Comment: CASE WHEN YEAR(START_DATE) = YEAR(END_DATE) THEN START_DATE
                             ELSE  DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,LAG(END_DATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY END_DATE))+1,0) 
                          END AS START_DATE

This is how i tried generating new start_dates based on end_dates. Any how the condition in the case is a temporary fix for my problem.

Comment: Observe dates carefully and their prices. Dnt know if it is that difficult.

Comment: where are the prices came from you have posted only Start and End dates

Comment: If you take the general case of date ranges, this can be quite difficult to solve in a single query - it's one of the few cases where the "least work" solution was actually to use a cursor and iterate through the data. For instance, you don't say whether or not it's possible for someone to add a date range of e.g. `01-01-2000` to `01-01-2999` later on.  Also, what rule is used to decide which date range "wins" - is it always shorter date range, highest price, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, +1 if You happy

```
-- Data Samples
declare @X table ( Price int, datefrom datetime, dateto datetime)
insert @X values ( 1, '1.1.2014','1.1.2016'),(2,'1.4.2014','1.5.2014'),(3,'1.7.2014','1.8.2014');

-- Check samples
select * from @X;

-- Query
with Dat as ( 
            select datefrom from @X
            union
            select dateto from @X 
)
, Periods as ( 
            select datefrom,dateto = LEAD(datefrom,1) over (order by datefrom) 
            from Dat
)
,val as ( select Pr.*,P.*
            from Periods P 
            cross apply ( select top 1 Price from @X
                        where P.datefrom between datefrom and dateto - 0.000001
                        order by DATEDIFF(day,datefrom,dateto)
            ) Pr

)

select * from val
```

Output

```
Price       datefrom                dateto
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
3           2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000

(3 row(s) affected)

Price       datefrom                dateto
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-04-01 00:00:00.000
2           2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
3           2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
1           2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I think it'll work only if You have one long period and some short periods. In other case you shoul change conditions in val part of cte

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
    (2, '2014-04-01', '2014-05-01'),
    (3, '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01')
    ) as t(X, [START_DATE], [END_DATE])
)
,dates AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY d.[Date] ) as r,
        d.[Date]
FROM (
    SELECT c.START_DATE as [Date] FROM cte c
    UNION 
    SELECT c.END_DATE as [Date] FROM cte c
) as d)

SELECT  MAX(c.X) AS X,
        d.[Date] AS [START_DATE],
        d1.[Date] AS [END_DATE]
FROM dates d 
INNER JOIN dates d1 ON d.r = d1.r-1
LEFT JOIN cte c ON d.[Date] BETWEEN c.START_DATE and c.END_DATE AND d1.[Date] BETWEEN c.START_DATE and c.END_DATE
GROUP BY d.[Date], d1.[Date]
```

Results:

```
X           START_DATE END_DATE
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2014-01-01 2014-04-01
2           2014-04-01 2014-05-01
1           2014-05-01 2014-07-01
3           2014-07-01 2014-08-01
1           2014-08-01 2016-01-01

(5 row(s) affected)
```

But if you add some new range which will cover another (like this `(6, '2014-07-15', '2015-08-01')`)  you should change that query.